# Squid listen multiple ports and forward request to another proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to setup a proxy that listen for multiple ports and each port forward the requests to another proxy, but each port maps to another unique port, for example:

```
LISTEN          FORWARD TO 
1.2.3.4:3128 -> 5.6.7.8:1111
1.2.3.4:3129 -> 5.6.7.8:2222
1.2.3.4:3130 -> 5.6.7.8:3333
```

Is this possible to implement with squid?